# Datetime does not work in my index series

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a hf5 filled with some data.

when I open it in python I have this output

```
hf['SB'].head()

0_1                     price   cng     
2015-07-15 07:30:00.087 12.61   4
2015-07-15 07:30:00.087 12.61   1
2015-07-15 07:30:00.087 12.61   1
2015-07-15 07:30:00.087 12.61   2
2015-07-15 07:30:00.087 12.61   19
```

This file ranges from 2015 to 2016.

```
hf['SB'].index

DatetimeIndex(['2015-07-15 07:30:00.087000', '2015-07-15 07:30:00.087000',
               '2015-07-15 07:30:00.087000', '2015-07-15 07:30:00.087000',
               '2015-07-15 07:30:00.087000', '2015-07-15 07:30:00.087000',
               '2015-07-15 07:30:00.087000', '2015-07-15 07:30:00.087000',
               '2015-07-15 07:30:00.087000', '2015-07-15 07:30:00.087000',
               ...
               '2016-07-14 16:59:57.670000', '2016-07-14 16:59:58.047000',
               '2016-07-14 16:59:59.170000', '2016-07-14 16:59:59.170000',
               '2016-07-14 16:59:59.170000', '2016-07-14 16:59:59.170000',
               '2016-07-14 16:59:59.170000', '2016-07-14 16:59:59.170000',
               '2016-07-14 16:59:59.170000', '2016-07-14 16:59:59.957000'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'0_1', length=3961015, freq=None)
```

Well... My problem is:

when I want a slice, for example, august 20 2015:

```
hf['SB'][datetime(2015,8,20)]
```

I got this error: `KeyError: datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 20, 0, 0)`

But if I use:

```
hf['SB']['2015-08-20']
```

its works!!!

There is something wrong in my index file or I'm using `datetime` function wrong?

Comment: Try converting the `datetime(2015,8,20)` to a string, e.g., `hf['SB']['{}'.format(datetime(2015,8,20)]`

Comment: Same error: KeyError: '2015-08-20 00:00:00'

I think this error is because when convert to a string you take exact hour and minutes, e.g., 00:00:00. Since my data doesn't have this exact value, I got this error

Comment: Try `hf['SB']['{}'.format(datetime(2015,8,20).date()]`

Comment: hey, its work... =] 

but I didn't understand why simple "datetime(2015,8,20)" doesn't work. Last year I use this same idea and worked very well. Maybe the function changed... 

Well, thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, that you are truing to get value for a key which is not present in index at all. `hf['SB']['2015-08-20']` will give you all records for that particular date.
See example below:

```
>>> rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2016', periods=10, freq='S')
>>> ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
>>> ts = ts[1:]

>>> ts
2016-01-01 00:00:01    0.133551
2016-01-01 00:00:02    1.067772
2016-01-01 00:00:03    0.591676
2016-01-01 00:00:04   -2.445586
2016-01-01 00:00:05    0.700155
2016-01-01 00:00:06   -0.127861
2016-01-01 00:00:07    1.116494
2016-01-01 00:00:08   -0.427959
2016-01-01 00:00:09    2.115352
Freq: S, dtype: float64

>>> ts[datetime.date(2016,1,1)]
....
KeyError: datetime.date(2016, 1, 1)

>>>  ts['2016-01-01']

2016-01-01 00:00:01    0.133551
2016-01-01 00:00:02    1.067772
2016-01-01 00:00:03    0.591676
2016-01-01 00:00:04   -2.445586
2016-01-01 00:00:05    0.700155
2016-01-01 00:00:06   -0.127861
2016-01-01 00:00:07    1.116494
2016-01-01 00:00:08   -0.427959
2016-01-01 00:00:09    2.115352
Freq: S, dtype: float64
```

so with `hf['SB']['2015-08-20']` you are getting all records for '2015-08-20', but none for `datetime.datetime(2015,8,20,0,0)`

if you want a slice using datetime, try following:

```
>>> ts[datetime.datetime(2016,1,1,0,0,1):datetime.datetime(2016,1,1,0,0,3)]

2016-01-01 00:00:01    0.133551
2016-01-01 00:00:02    1.067772
2016-01-01 00:00:03    0.591676
Freq: S, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. But if I want a slice for a week for example your suggestion fail, cause I need know exact the time of first to last point.

Can you suggest another way to slice this kind of information ??

Comment: if you want to slice, you should know the slice range - check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437460/pandas-slice-dataframe-by-datetime-that-may-not-exist-and-return-view) for some other examples. also check [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex) for more info of what attributes and methods are available for DateTimeIndex (week number for example).