# Selecting date and time within a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
    Date            MBs     GBs
0   2018-08-14 20:10    32.00 MB    0.00 GB
1   2018-08-14 20:05    4.00 MB     0.00 GB
2   2018-08-14 20:00    1000.99 MB  1.23 GB
```

Ive already done this :

```
na_aus['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(na_aus['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

But when i try to do a simple filter like this :

```
na_aus.loc['2018-08-14 19:50' : '2018-08-14 20:10']
```

All I get is:

```
Date            MBs     GBs
```

With no data returned.

I tried following this [Select dataframe rows between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates#29370182) but its not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437460/pandas-slice-dataframe-by-datetime-that-may-not-exist-and-return-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
na_aus.loc[na_aus['Date'].between('2018-08-14 19:50','2018-08-14 20:10')]
```

In your case, all rows satisfy the requirement:

```
                 Date         MBs      GBs
0 2018-08-14 20:10:00    32.00 MB  0.00 GB
1 2018-08-14 20:05:00     4.00 MB  0.00 GB
2 2018-08-14 20:00:00  1000.99 MB  1.23 GB
```

But if you don't want it to include the boundaries, set `inclusive=False`. This means that because row 0 is the exact border of your range, it won't be included:

```
>>> na_aus.loc[na_aus['Date'].between('2018-08-14 19:50', '2018-08-14 20:10',
                                      inclusive=False)]


                 Date         MBs      GBs
1 2018-08-14 20:05:00     4.00 MB  0.00 GB
2 2018-08-14 20:00:00  1000.99 MB  1.23 GB
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: actually can you add your example for multiple ranges. For instance, if you wanted 2018-08-13 19:50','2018-08-14 20:10 slice and also 2018-08-12 19:50','2018-08-12 20:10 for example but not the rest so I only have a DF of ranges I want is that possible?

Comment: use `|` operator .. `df.loc[df.between(a, b) | df.between(c, d)]`

Comment: I was about to say the same as @RafaelC