# trying to figure out a pythonic way of code that is taking time even after using list comprehension and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have two dataframes: one comprising a large data set, `allprice_df`, with time price series for all stocks; and the other, `init_df`, comprising selective stocks and trade entry dates. I am trying to find the highest price for each ticker symbol and its associated date.

The following code works but it is time consuming, and I am wondering if there is a better, more Pythonic way to accomplish this.

```
# Initial call
init_df = init_df.assign(HighestHigh = lambda x: 
  highestHigh(x['DateIdentified'], x['Ticker'], allprice_df))

# HighestHigh function in lambda call
def highestHigh(date1,ticker,allp_df):
      if date1.size == ticker.size:
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['DateIdentified','Ticker'])
        temp_df['DateIdentified'] = date1
        temp_df['Ticker'] = ticker
    else:
        print("dates and tickers size mismatching")
        sys.exit(1)
    counter = itertools.count(0)
    high_list = [getHigh(x,y,allp_df, next(counter)) for x, y in zip(temp_df['DateIdentified'],temp_df['Ticker'])]
    return high_list

# Getting high for each ticker
def getHigh(dateidentified,ticker,allp_df, count):
     print("trade %s" % count)
    currDate = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    allpm_df = allp_df.loc[((allp_df['Ticker']==ticker)&(allp_df['date']>dateidentified)&(allp_df['date']<=currDate)),['high','date']]
    hh = allpm_df.iloc[:,0].max()
    hd = allpm_df.loc[(allpm_df['high']==hh),'date']
    hh = round(hh,2)
    h_list  = [hh,hd]
    return h_list

# Split the list in to 2 columns one with price and the other with the corresponding date
init_df = split_columns(init_df,"HighestHigh")

# The function to split the list elements in to different columns
def split_columns(orig_df,col):
    split_df = pd.DataFrame(orig_df[col].tolist(),columns=[col+"Mod", col+"Date"])
    split_df[col+"Date"] = split_df[col+"Date"].apply(lambda x: x.squeeze())
    orig_df = pd.concat([orig_df,split_df], axis=1)
    orig_df = orig_df.drop(col,axis=1)
    orig_df = orig_df.rename(columns={col+"Mod": col})
    return orig_df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of obvious solutions that would help reduce your runtime.

First, in your `getHigh` function, instead of using `loc` to get the date associated with the maximum value for `high`, use `idxmax` to get the index of the row associated with the high and then access that row:

```
hh, hd = allpm_df[allpm_df['high'].idxmax()]
```

This will replace two O(N) operations (finding the maximum in a list, and doing a list lookup using a comparison) with one O(N) operation and one O(1) operation.

**Edit**

In light of your information on the size of your dataframes, my best guess is that this line is probably where most of your time is being consumed:

```
allpm_df = allp_df.loc[((allp_df['Ticker']==ticker)&(allp_df['date']>dateidentified)&(allp_df['date']<=currDate)),['high','date']]
```

In order to make this faster, I would setup your data frame to include a multi-index when you first create the data frame:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays = [ticker_symbols, dates], names = ['Symbol', 'Date'])
allp_df = pd.Dataframe(data, index = index)
allp_df.index.sortlevel(level = 0, sort_remaining = True)
```

This should create a dataframe with a sorted, multi-level index associated with your ticker symbol and date. Doing this will reduce your search time tremendously. Once you do that, you should be able to access all the data associated with a ticker symbol and a given date-range by doing this:

```
allp_df[ticker, (dateidentified: currDate)]
```

which should return your data much more quickly. For more information on multi-indexing, check out this helpful Pandas [tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html).

Comment: You mean: allpm_df = allp_df.loc[((allp_df['Ticker']==ticker)&(allp_df['date']>dateidentified)&(allp_df['date']<=currDate)),['high','date']]
    hh = allpm_df.iloc[:,0].max()
    hd = allpm_df.at[allpm_df['high'].idxmax(),'date']
    hh = round(hh,2)
    h_list  = [hh,hd]
    return h_list; it didnt really improve the speed

Comment: @sud Interesting. Without knowing more about the size of the data frames you're working with, there's not much more I can help with.

Comment: init_df is around 4000 rows and 30 columns; allprice_df is around 25M rows and 5 columns; allp_df is around 10000 rows an 20 columns - all columns either integers or floats except 1 or 2 which are strings

Comment: In that case, your limiting factor is going to be operations done on `allprice_df`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I tried a bit differently to set the multi-index: allp_df.set_index(['Ticker', 'date'],drop=True, inplace=True)
allp_df.index.sortlevel(level = 0, sort_remaining = True); but accessing statement is giving me syntax error:  allpm_df = allp_df[ticker, (dateidentified: currDate)] - i searched to see if i need to use slice...but couldnt find any....

Comment: additional info dates are type: datetime.date;  I changed the code line to : allpm_df = allp_df.loc[(ticker, slice(dateidentified,currDate)], and now i got rid of syntax error and got  KeyError: datetime.date(2021, 12, 20)

Comment: @sud I wasn't aware you were working with datetime objects. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437460/pandas-slice-dataframe-by-datetime-that-may-not-exist-and-return-view) may be of some help then.

Comment: Thanks...if not datetime ...what could those date variables be that your code works?

Comment: @sud You're getting that error because one of the slice limits isn't in the index. So, you should probably use `loc` like in the link I provided.

Comment: Added this code: allpm_df = allp_df.loc[(allprice_df.index.get_level_values(0) == ticker) & (allprice_df.index.get_level_values(1) > dateidentified) & (allprice_df.index.get_level_values(1) < currDate)] - unfortunately, it didnt seem to have improved the speed from the first version of the code i had..!

Comment: any further improvisations to speed up the code....it is so slow right now..!

Comment: @sud Sorry, I don't see any other obvious places where performance could be improved.